# Custom module allows permission only for full admin in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, permissions, magento-1.9, acl, adminhtml

I have created a custom module in Magento 1.9 and I want to access that module only if I'm logged in on a full admin account, but I want this to be default. If I'm logged in with another role, I don't want to have access at this module at all. And when I create a new user role, I don't want to have any option at **Role Resources** because I don't want any of my admin users to give permission by mistake to any other role users. Is this possible?

Shortly: This module can be access only if I am logged in on a full admin user and I don't want any checkbox option on **role resources** because any other role cannot access the module. This module is only for admin panel.

If I don't add the **acl** tag in **adminhtml.xml**, I get a **404 Error** on **System->Configuration** on module section.

This is my **acl** tag:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <namespace_modulename translate="title" module="namespace_modulename">
                                    <title>module-title</title>
                                </namespace_modulename>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Can anyone help me with that? I'm not sure if the **acl** is correctly created.

Answer (score 1):

The only option I see would be to alter the content of the `isAllowed` method in your controller.
There you can check if the id or name of the current user group is the one from the admin group.
This will prevent any other group to access the page. But it will still be visible in the menu if the checkbox in the acl is checked.